# Cant set color in searchbar of Searchbar display Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uisearchbar

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];

[searchBar setTranslucent:NO];


searchBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:92.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:178.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);


self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                                                                     contentsController:self];

 self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

 self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;


 self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

in above code i want to set the color in search bar of SearchBarDisplay Controller but i cant set it properly...[image: this is the screen shot of search display controller] pls tell me solution...thanks

[image: i want this type of color in searchbar display controller's searchbar]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a background image to customize the search text field background:

```
- (void)setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state
```

See 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/searchFieldBackgroundImageForState:

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   [sBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [sBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar_bg"]];

   [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] ];
```